# Unity. Собранный APK не запускается (чёрный экран)

Tags: android, unity3d, разработка-игр, unity3d-android

Собранный билд под андроид в Unity 2020.3.15f2 не запускается на устройстве, просто показывает чёрный экран, ничего не происходит больше. (на эмуляторе происходит тоже самое). В чём может быть проблема?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможных причин - буквально, без шуток, тысячи. Велика вероятность сократить возможные варианты до единиц, если бы была возможность посмотреть логи.

Comment: https://answers.unity.com/questions/1329886/android-black-screen-when-built.html, из этого диспута, проверьте размер текстур не должен быть больше 512

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо за помощь, проблема оказалась в неправильно заполненном scriptable object "GoogleMobileAdsSettings"